# Getting SerializationException while producing avro records to an avro kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We have an akka-scala application and we are avroizing the incoming messages. After that we are trying to write that message to a kafka topic which is an avro kafka topic. While writing we are getting the below exception:

**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Internal Server Error; error code: 500**

We have checked that the schema registry is working fine and subject and version exist. We are not registering any new schema, that already exists. We are using scala 2.13.8 and tried with different confluent kafka avro serializer version like 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 6.1.3. Can you please tell what might be the cause of this.

Comment: You need to look at the registry server logs. Apparently, it's not working fine if it's having "internal server errors"

Comment: But, when we get into a pod and do curl to the schema registry endpoint, we get 200 response. We are also retrieving the schema by using curl from the pods.

Comment: Then your external client is passing some extraneous HTTP headers/content that the server cannot process, which should be indicated from the logs. You can also set `debug=true` in its properties to get more information. Without those logs, we cannot answer what the problem may be

Comment: What we found out that it is trying to register the schema which already exists. From this issue reported, it looks like we might get 500 error in such scenarios:  
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1715  I am trying to disable auto.register.schemas in producer settings itself.

Comment: Yes, the producer will always try to register its schema. Mainly to check compatibility if it had changed between requests... But the server logs will still indicate the real error

Answer (score 0):

After disabling auto register schemas, this error was fixed. We have set the flag `auto.register.schemas = false` in the producer settings and that fixed the problem.

Below is the complete producer settings for the reference:

```
object KafkaSinkSettings {
  val BootstrapServers = sys.env.get(Constants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
  val ProducerConfig = Constants.PRODUCER_CONFIG
  val SchemaRegistryUrl = sys.env.get(Constants.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL)
  val Topic = sys.env.get(Constants.TOPIC)
  val ClientId = Constants.METRICS_PREFIX
  val MaxInFlightReqPerConn = sys.env.get(Constants.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION)
  val RetriesConfig = sys.env.get(Constants.RETRIES_CONFIG)
  val RequestTimeoutMSConfig = sys.env.get(Constants.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG)
  val RetryBackoffMsConfig = sys.env.get(Constants.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG)

  def apply(implicit config: Config): KafkaSinkSettings = new KafkaSinkSettings()
}

class KafkaSinkSettings(implicit config: Config) {

  val producerConfig = config.getConfig(KafkaSinkSettings.ProducerConfig)

  val kafkaAvroSerDeConfig = Map[String, Any](
    AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG -> KafkaSinkSettings.SchemaRegistryUrl.getOrElse(
      config.getString("kafka.schema-registry-url")),
    AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS -> config.getString("kafka.auto-register-schemas"),

    ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> KafkaSinkSettings.BootstrapServers.getOrElse(
      config.getString("kafka.bootstrap-servers")),
    KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG -> true.toString
  )


 
  def createAvroProducerSettings(): ProducerSettings[String, AnyRef] = {

    val kafkaAvroSerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer()
    kafkaAvroSerializer.configure(kafkaAvroSerDeConfig.asJava, false)

    val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(producerConfig, new StringSerializer, kafkaAvroSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(KafkaSinkSettings.BootstrapServers.getOrElse(
        config.getString("kafka.bootstrap-servers")))
      .withProperty(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, KafkaSinkSettings.ClientId + randomClientIdPostfix)
      .withProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, KafkaSinkSettings.MaxInFlightReqPerConn.getOrElse(
        config.getString("kafka.max-in-flight-requests-per-connection")
      ))
      .withProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, KafkaSinkSettings.RetriesConfig.getOrElse(
        config.getString("kafka.retries-config")
      ))
      .withProperty(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, KafkaSinkSettings.RequestTimeoutMSConfig.getOrElse(
        config.getString("kafka.request-timeout-ms-config")
      ))
      .withProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, KafkaSinkSettings.RetryBackoffMsConfig.getOrElse(
        config.getString("kafka.retry-backoff-ms-config")
      ))
 
    producerSettings
  }

}
```